# Is there a developer-friendly open standard / ontology for personal health data?

Tags: medical, uses-of-open-data, ontology, standards

I am looking to organize and centralize all my personal health data in a machine-readable format on my self-hosted private server. My intention is to have a consolidated, single source of information that encompasses a variety of data points such as:

- **Events**: This would cover the spectrum of my healthcare interactions such as doctor visits and various medical tests I've undergone along with their results.
- **Medical Records**: I would like to incorporate the patient records I've received from healthcare providers. These should include information such as diagnoses and prescriptions.
- **Personal Health Measurements**: I am also interested in integrating self-measured data like blood pressure and weight to this data repository.

My motivation for this endeavor is the belief that an open standard could facilitate an ecosystem of applications designed to enhance usability of such data, offer insights, provide reminders, and so on.

**Is there an existing open standard that caters to the requirements I have mentioned?**